# I need the url for TFS for TeamCity?

Tags: teamcity

I have setup teamcity in the past with Subversion, no problem. I have never used TFS before. We have TFS 2010 running and I can connect to via Visual Studio 2010. How do I find the URL for TeamCity? I am using TeamCity 6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the configured TFS URL from within Visual Studio by picking View -> Team Explorer, then looking at the top node. (I'm assuming for a second that you have only one TFS server set up; otherwise, there should be multiple top-level nodes.)

If you right-click on it and pick Properties, it will show you the full URL including protocol and port.

This is for Visual Studio 2008, but I'm pretty sure it's the same in 2010.